# Swift / SpriteKit Button Drag Off Cancel Not Working?

Tags: swift

Hello I need your help I have been looking a while now to find the Answer to this.

I also have simplified the code to get rid of allot of the information/junk you don't need to know.

I have a main menu scene in for a IOS game using SpriteKit And Swift.  There Is a main menu play button. What I want is When the button is pressed the button get bigger by a little. When the my finger is release the button gets smaller. This works fine using override func touchesBegan / touchesEnded. my problem is when my finger gets dragged off the button like to cancel. The button does not return to the original size. I am pretty sure I need to use

```
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {}
```

But upon many attempts I am not getting the the desired result of returning the button to original size when my finger is dragged off the button. Thanks for any help.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class StartScene: SKScene {

    var playButton: SKNode! = nill  

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        // Create PlayButton image
        playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playButtonStatic")
        // location of Button
        playButton.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:520);
        self.addChild(playButton)
        playButton.setScale(0.5)
}



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
                if playButton.containsPoint(location) {
                   playButton.setScale(0.6)}}}



override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if playButton.containsPoint(location) {
                playButton.setScale(0.5)
        }}}



// Problem Area

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches! {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if playButton.containsPoint(location) {
               playButton.setScale(0.5)
        }}}

}
```

Thanks for any response

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution use a Else statement in TouchesEnded

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

for touch: AnyObject in touches {

    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if playButton.containsPoint(location) {
            playButton.setScale(0.5)

    }
        else
        {
            playButton.setScale(0.5)
    }}
```

Comment: FAARRKKKKKKK I need this. Thank you!!!! I was battling with how to do this inside a button for ages... until now.

Comment: glad to help it took me a while too

Answer (score 1):

You say you found a solution but here's an easier solution: use a custom class I created designed specifically for buttons for SpriteKit. [Link to the GitHub that has the class file.](https://github.com/jozemite/JKButtonNode) With this class, you don't have to worry about it at all, and it removes unnecessary code from your touches functions. JKButtonNodes have 3 states: normal, highlighted, and disabled. You also don't have to worry about setting it to nil if you have removed it from the parent.

To declare a variable, do this. Ignore the playButtonAction error for now.

```
var playButton = JKButtonNode(background: SKTexture(imageNamed: "playButtonStatic"), action: playButtonAction)
```

The action is the function to call when the button is pressed and let go. Create a function like this anywhere in your class.

```
func playButtonAction(button: JKButtonNode) {
    //Whatever the button does when pressed goes here
}
```

Then you can set its properties in didMoveToView.

```
playButton.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:520)

//These are the 3 images you want to be used when pressed/disabled
//You can create a bigger image for when pressed as you want.
playButton.setBackgroundsForState(normal: "playButtonStatic", highlighted: "playButtonHighlighted", disabled: "")

addChild(playButton)
```

And that's it! The JKButtonNode class itself already cancels touches if the user moves their finger off, it also doesn't call the function unless the user has successfully pressed the button and released their finger on it. You can also do other things like disable it from playing sounds, etc.

A good pro of using JKButtonNode is that you don't have to have code all over the place anymore since it doesn't require ANY code in the touches functions.

Comment: This is great, Thank you